# Как сделать одинакового размера два объекта, которые находятся в QVBoxLayout()?

Tags: python, pyqt5

Ребят такой вопрос, у меня есть рамка и кнопка, когда я их добавляю в форму QVBoxLayout(), то рамка занимает все пространство и кнопка небольшая снизу, а я хочу чтобы кнопка была такого же размер как и рамка вот что у меня сейчас:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А хочу чтобы было вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QFrame, QVBoxLayout, QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton


class Main(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Main, self).__init__()
        self.resize(400, 400)
        self.setStyleSheet('background-color: #bdd3de;')
        self.fream1 = QFrame()
        self.fream1.setFrameStyle(QFrame.Box)
        self.fream1.setStyleSheet('''QFrame {
                                    background-color: #ffffff;
                                    border-radius: 30px;
                }''')
        self.btn_test = QPushButton('test')

        self.main_box = QVBoxLayout()
        self.main_box.addWidget(self.fream1)
        self.main_box.addWidget(self.btn_test)
        self.setLayout(self.main_box)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    main = Main()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Размеры и возможность их изменяться при ресайзе виджетов зависят от `sizePolicy`. По умолчанию, для `QPushButton` политика изменения вертикального размера `Fixed`. Задайте свою политику, чтобы изменить устанавливаемые размеры и поведение при ресайзе для кнопки.
Как простой пример, можно сделать `sizePolicy` для кнопки и фрейма одинаковыми:

```
self.btn_test.setSizePolicy(self.fream1.sizePolicy())
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло